# How to make a text input scroll to exact position on focus using a keyboard aware scroll view in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have read the [docs](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view) but still don't understand how to make the text input scroll to an exact position. I want the text input to automatically scroll to the very top of the screen just below my Header component. Using the following code below, could anyone provide an example of how this is done? Thanks.

```
<KeyboardAwareScrollView>
            <TextInput
                style={{
                fontSize: 18,
                width: "100%",
                textAlignVertical: "center",
                        }}
                autoFocus={true}
                blurOnSubmit={false}
                value={name}
                onChangeText={(text: string) => {
                    setName(text);
                        }}
                />
</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

Comment: I am also using functional based components and all of the examples are using class based components.

Comment: wait can you share an image how it hsould look like?